# Calling scripts from External file using document.onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, document-ready

I want to load two scripts from an external file without using JQuery.  Is there any way that I can fire these two files when my document is completely loaded all the dependencies, iframes, images etc. I am seeing lot of codes but none of them are pure js.  I am no expert in codes. Simply give the code so that I can copy paste my external js src files in the code.

Regards
Ramakrishna

Answer (score -1):

basics! thats all:

```
<script src="/jsFile.js"> </script>
```

`<script src="/jsFile2.js"> </script>`

check this to learn more about js [enter link description here](https://www.codecademy.com/learn)

Comment: This is not the solution I needed.  I need complete code to be put along with source files in an external file, so that after the page loaded, these two should fire.